# Getting store dump in Chrome/Firefox Javascript console?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I use a lot of Sencha stores in my app.  Is there a way to dump them to the Javascript console in Chrome/Firefox so that I can quickly see what I have loaded in any given one while my app is running?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    models: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', ...],

    stores: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', ...],

    views: [...],

    controllers: [...],


    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Sencha.view.MainView'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ext.getStore`:

```
Ext.getStore('One');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [Ext.data.StoreManager](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager). From there you can access each store you have created in your app.

Hope this helps